# Jmeter: User login and hit multiple URL and Logout

Tags: jmeter

I want to make a script in which user login and do multiple stuff

1. user login
2. hit URL by CSV (Done)
3. logout

How can i hit all *URLs* from *CSV* for one user (Thread only)

Comment: Please clarify about what you are asking. Logging in and out? Parsing CSV? Sending a few request to different URLs from one script? Your question mentions all of them, but without any details what you do and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience @ruslan , step 1 - login ,  step 2 - hit 10 different URLs with CSV file configuration , step 3 - logout . I did step 2 but while i set thread user as one then in step 2 its just fetching first url from csv file (file contains 10 URLs). so how could i make script using single thread to do once only login and then hit all URLs from file and then step 3 -logout. Hope u understand . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) with the following condition:

```
${__javaScript("${myVar}" != "<EOF>",)}
```

where

- `myVar` is your CSV variable
- `__javaScript()` is a [JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript)

If you put your Logout Sampler and CSV Data Set Config under the While Controller and configure your CSV Data Set Config like:

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

Your test will cycle through CSV file and continue to the Logout sampler.

Check out **Reading all Values from the CSV and Continue** chapter of the [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) guide for step-by-step instructions.